# Regarding a crossword

Tags: crosswords

[image: a 7-by-7 highly symmetric crossword grid with three across and three down lights, each of length 7, intersecting in all even-numbered positions; all odd-numbered positions are unchecked]

#### Down

1. *any of* `bcbbbccccbc` `ccbcbcccbcbcca` `ba` `ccca` `ca` *but none of* `a` `bcaa`
2. *any of* `aaaaaaaaac` `aaaaaaaaaaaa` `a2aaaaaa` `a2ac` *but none of* `2aaaac` `a2aaaacc` `a22ac`
3. *any of*  `234cb` `234b` `23444444cb` `234444444b` *but none of* `24cb` `24b` `2cb` `3cb` `23cb` `234ccb`

#### Across

4. *either of* `abb` `abbb` *but none of* `abbbb` `ab` `aabb`
5. *either of* `]abc` `]abbbbc` *but none of* `]ac` `]bc` `]ab` `abc` `]]abc`
6. *either of* `abca` `a` *but none of* `aa` `aba` `cba` `abba` `bcca`

Comment: This is my first puzzle of this sort and I request critiques and ideas for improvement.

Comment: Sounds like it belongs [here](https://regexcrossword.com/), but not quite? :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think I solved it

> The strings of characters in the clues seem like they can be described by regular expressions.
>
> ```
>   [   a   2
> a b { 2 , 3 } 
>   c   ?   4
> ( ] ) a b + c
>   +   +   c
> ( a b c ) ? a
>   ?   ?   b
> ```
>
> Down
> 1 `[bc]+a?` (at least one of `b` or `c` (or mixed), then optional `a`)
> 2 `a2?a+c?` (`a`, then optional `2`, then at least one `a`, then optional `c`)
> 3 `234+c?b` (`23`, then at least one `4`, optional `c`, then `b`)
> Across
> 4 `ab{2,3}` (`a`, then exactly 2 or 3 `b`'s)
> 5 `(])ab+c` (`]`, then `a`, then at least one `b`, then `c`)
> 6 `(abc)?a` (optional `abc`, then `a`)
>
> The cell where 3 and 6 meet could also be a `*` and satisfy the conditions.

I liked this puzzle, I've never seen anything like it. The only improvement I can see is if you made it have only one solution (maybe by adding more negative test cases).

Comment: I fixed 5 across. Also I meant to say you could replace it with a `*`

Comment: Excellent. 5 Across was actually meant to be `[]]ab+c` — which supports your point that I should've worked harder at making this have a unique solution.

Comment: Just for curiosity, what are you using to test your regex? Using Javascript `[]]` doesn't match `]`, whereas `(])` (or even `]`) does match.

Comment: Perl 5. `[]]` matches just the character `]` there.

Comment: I'm guessing some regex parsers will count `[]]` as an empty set followed by `]`. It looks like Perl treats is as a set containing `]`.

Comment: I'd hazard a guess that the title is also a clue: Re is a synonym for regarding and RE is the abbreviation for Regular Expression

Comment: yes, exactly, @postmortes

Comment: @MatthewJensen If you liked the puzzle and have never seen anything like it, let me ruin your productivity for the rest of the day: https://regexcrossword.com/

Comment: I actually saw that in a comment on this question, although it's still a regex crossword, it's the reverse (the clues are regexes, instead of answers). It was still a lot of fun!